# How to change color of paper-button's paper-material box shadow? (Polymer 1.0+)

Tags: css, polymer, paper-elements

Just wondering how I might go about changing the color of a paper-button's box shadow (button's toggles attribute enabled), in a dynamic fashion (i.e. based on a host element property value)?  The 'shadow color' property isn't something that is currently exposed in it's api, and I'm not sure how one would even change the paper-button's child paper-material properties in such a way.

Answer (score 1):

The shadow for `paper-button` comes from a `paper-material` inside.

To style the shadow of `paper-material` you can use these mixins (different depending on elevation):

- --shadow-elevation-2dp
- --shadow-elevation-3dp
- --shadow-elevation-4dp
- --shadow-elevation-6dp
- --shadow-elevation-8dp

Here's a [working example](http://jsbin.com/loqaqa/9/edit?html,output)

Comment: jsbin is down... Can you post your example here?